# Second Last records

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the second last records use mysql.
I did some research, some sample has fix gap between numbers or date. But my situation is that the contract_id is not always +1 from the previous one. Anyone ideas? Thank you so much.

```html
merchant_id    contract_id     start_date
10               501            2016-05-01
10               506            2016-06-01
13               456            2015-12-01
13               462            2016-01-01
14               620            2016-06-01
14               642            2016-07-01
14               656            2016-07-05
 
 
merchant_id   Second_last_contract_id
10             501
13             456
14             642
```

contract_id != previous contract_id + X.  (The X is not fixed)

'start_date' tell us the contracts creating order.

Comment: Why    501, 456, 642 .? .   should be  501, 456, 620 or  506, 462, 642 ..

Comment: I just want to make sure people know that the contract_id is not continuous number, and not always equal to previous contract_id + X

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option using `user-defined variables` to establish a row number per group of merchants and then filtering on the 2nd in each group ordered by contracts:

```
select * 
from (
  select *, 
      @rn:=if(@prevMerchantId=merchantid,
              @rn+1,
              if(@prevMerchantId:=merchantid, 1, 1)
              ) as rn
  from yourtable cross join (select @rn:=0, @prevMerchantId:=null) t
  order by merchantId, contractid desc
  ) t
where rn = 2
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e4f75/3)

Comment: Hi Sgeddes. Thank you for your solution. It looks complicated... I just add a new column 'start_date', which indicate the contract create date/order. Is it any other way to make the query much more simple?

Comment: @qqqwww -- just change the `order by` in the subquery.  Using `user-defined variables` is a pretty common approach, but there are others.  Play with the inner subquery and you can see how it's establishing row numbers per group.  Then filtering is easy at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option, filtering the results of [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) using [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
SELECT   merchant_id,
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
             GROUP_CONCAT(contract_id ORDER BY start_date DESC),
         ',', 2), ',', -1) AS Second_last_contract_id
FROM     the_table
GROUP BY merchant_id
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8616b9/1/0).